# Using NsMutableArray how to fetch data from Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a coredata table I want to search NSMutable array data. This is my mutable array data using this data want to find out corresponding id, major, minor, uuid have corresponding id. So in array I have 5 data so 5 data have corresponding 5 different ids how to retrive this:

```
{
    major = 1;
    minor = 6000;
    uuid = "wwwwwwww";
},
    {
    major = 1;
    minor = 4541;
    uuid = "eeeeee";
},
```

Am using this code to fetching but app is crashing

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DatabeaconBasket" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"major IN %@", self.beaconListArray];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to execute fetch request.");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);

} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

Comment: What is the crash message?  Which line does it crash on?

Comment: Crash? What crash?

Comment: @Paulw11

    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

on this line app is crashing(exit)

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17427f9c0'

Comment: @Larme

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17427f9c0'

Comment: i Want to search with these 3 parameters, then only will get corresponding id.how can we achieve that and that present in the nsmutablearray

Comment: What is `self.beaconListArray`? Is the the thing your posted before hand? If yes, try with `@"major IN %@", [self.beaconListArray valueForKeyPath:@"major"]`?

Comment: @Larme 
self.beaconListArray is the data contain array using these value i want search in coredata

i need to search with 3 parameter and these are in NSMutable array
{
    major = 1;
    minor = 6000;
    uuid = "wwwwwwww";
},
    {
    major = 1;
    minor = 4541;
    uuid = "eeeeee";
},

Comment: And you filter only on `major` key?

Comment: @Larme
 i tried with that but that also error, same error coming

how to fetch coredata table using nsmutable objects.is any idea

Comment: The exception is not related to that code. The line `executeFetchRequest` cannot cause a crash. The error message reveals that you are trying to send a message to `NSDictionary` rather than an expected `NSNumber` object.